# How to know if a page is a news article?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension that will show me useful information when I'm reading a news article. There are 67 sites that I'm working with.

Some have "article" or "wcm" or "yyyy/mm/dd" that is consistent throughout their file structure. And I'm able to regex or just plain `url.indexOf(str)` to know that this is an article.

But for more than 30%, it's hard to predict, unless I go down to the html source and find something that is consistent like a date or author, but that seems a little tedious and/or performance hungry, especially when some have that infinite scroll inside their article content.

Was wondering if there was magical alternative...

Comment: There's no magical solution. Take a look at various `<meta>` tags, they may have similarities. As for performance, it all depends on implementation, it doesn't have to be hungry.

Comment: True have not thought about the meta tag, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Almost every news organization subscribes to the [open graph standard](https://ogp.me/) to enable rich embeds in article shares.

The standard [says](https://ogp.me/#no_vertical) that articles should have the meta property `og:type`'s content set to `article`

Therefore, if the page is an article, the following code should evaluate to true

```js
document.head.querySelector("[property~='og:type']").content == 'article'
```